# Comparing two correlations/regressions with a repeated variable?

Tags: regression, correlation, anova, linear-model, ancova

apologies this is possibly a repeat question but I have done a fair amount of googling and the answer is not obvious to me.

I have two variables each measured on different days. Say a_day1, a_day2, b_day1, b_day2. I want to test whether a_day1 is more correlated with a_day2 than b_day2 and same for b_day1. What is the most appropriate test here?

a and b tend to have a significant negative correlation or no correlation. within group, a/a and b/b tend to have a significant positive correlation.

One way to go about it is using a linear model and comparing the slopes between a_day1 and a_day2 vs. a_day1 and b_day2. In this case, there are two dependent variables (a_day2 vs b_day2), which have the same values for an independent variable (a_day1). Does it make sense to use a repeated measures ANOVA where the factor in question is A vs B? In that case if I understand correctly it's the same as a paired-samples t-test, but, in this case I don't want to compare the paired differences as both will be fairly symmetric, except A vs B will have more variance. Or is this appropriate for an ANCOVA?

Still this does not seem to be the most appropriate as I would have to run it twice for a and b. Is there a test that would account for all the relevant information? In a sense there are two factors, day and group (A vs B)

Thanks very much